# Missing Right parenthesis error?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to create a table in sqldeveloper however I keep getting a missing right parenthesis error when there are no missing right parenthises. Any fixes for this or am i just trying to create a table the wrong way?

```
CREATE TABLE Patient_T1(
  PATIENT_ID  INT(100) NOT NULL,
  FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  LAST_NAME   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  DOB         CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
  P_STREET_ADRESS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_CITY    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_STATE   CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_ZIP  CHAR(5)    NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_PHONE CHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_ROOM  INT(1000) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PATIENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(PATIENT_ID));
```

Comment: What's an `INT(100)`?

Comment: It's a large integer, lol.

Comment: You should probably also be using `varchar2()`.  And why is `DOB` a character string and not a date?

Comment: @TheShaman: there is no DBMS where `int(100)` would be a "*large*  integer"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, I was being humorous. The only time I have seen anything like that is in Ab Initio Metadata Portal where you specify the number of digits in an integer. But yes, there's no DBMS that uses that notation.

Comment: @TheShaman: actually MySQL uses that _notation_ but it has nothing to do with limiting the values for that column.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Oracle gives that error message instead of something more helpful, but the cause is the precision applied to `INT`, switch from `INT(100)` and `INT(1000)` to just `INT`:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient_T1(
  PATIENT_ID  INT NOT NULL,
  FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  LAST_NAME   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  DOB         CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
  P_STREET_ADRESS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_CITY    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_STATE   CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_ZIP  CHAR(5)    NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_PHONE CHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
  PATIENT_ROOM  INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PATIENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(PATIENT_ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your table **DDL**:

- `INT(100)` - In Oracle, an **INTEGER** is an **ANSI SQL data** type which refers to numeric values which have *only an integer portion and no floating point or decimal part*. That is, an INTEGER will only store **whole numbers** ONLY.
- `VARCHAR(20)` - Oracle strongly recommends to use **VARCHAR2**.

From [**documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1835),

> VARCHAR Datatype
>
> The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To
>   avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype
>   to store variable-length character strings.

- `CHAR(10)` - better use **VARCHAR2** as CHAR is blank-padded to the fixed length. That's a wastage of storage.

From **[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1960)**,

> CHAR Datatype
>
> The CHAR datatype stores fixed-length character strings. If you give a
>   shorter value, then the value is blank-padded to the fixed length.

Only the issue# 1 would throw an error, anyway fixing all the above issues would let you create the table.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Patient_T1
  2    (
  3      PATIENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  4      FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  5      LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  6      DOB DATE NOT NULL,
  7      P_STREET_ADRESS VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  8      PATIENT_CITY VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  9      PATIENT_STATE VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
 10      PATIENT_ZIP   VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
 11      PATIENT_PHONE VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
 12      PATIENT_ROOM  NUMBER NOT NULL,
 13      CONSTRAINT PATIENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(PATIENT_ID)
 14    );

Table created.
```